# How to use Scandit with Samsung Gear 2?

Tags: barcode-scanner, samsung-galaxy-gear

http://www.scandit.com/barcode-scanner-sdk/wearable-device-support/

According to their website, they support the wearable devices google glass and Gear 2. However I was not able to find any documentation or tutorial how to use scandit on Gear 2. Anyone have any answers or pointer? Any help would be appreciated

Also, if not scandit, could there be any other free sdk scanning libraries out there native to the Gear 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, Scandit will not work. They only support gear 1 for now. Try Eddiela's javascript version for barcode scanning. It works very nice for me, even with the gear 2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this issue. Below is my email to the Scandit team.

> Hi,
>
> The Samsung Gear 2 is using Tizen for which there is no Scandit SDK.
>   It works with the Gear 1 since that is Android base.
>
> Best regards, Moritz
>
> On 03/07/14 01:30, Ding, Cheng wrote: 
>   Hi, is there any documentation
>   as to how I can get Scandit working with the Gear 2?   I’d love to
>   user Scandit, but I just can’t find any
>   documentation/resources/tutorials.